# Responsive slider works everywhere except iPad Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I can't figure out why the slider breaks down on iPad Safari. It looks perfectly fine in other browsers. HERE: http://wordpress.business.illinois.edu/custom/. I've tried setting max-widths and 100% widths all over the place, but with no success. There's no chrome developer tool unfortunately for me to see what's wrong.

Comment: Care to provide a screenshot for those of us without an ipad?

Comment: on my iPad (Retina), it's just fine. you'd better provide us an image.

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant to update the post sooner. I linked the wrong page. It turns out I was editing the wrong css file. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was editing the wrong less file. Thanks to @EternalHour and @hina10531 for the help.